# What should I submit in-lieu on no objection certification for tourist visa for Japan when switching jobs?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, japan, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

I am planning to switch jobs in the next 1-2 months, with a 2 week break between the two. I want to take a trip to either Japan or Europe in this window.

Japan and Schengen visa requirements for Indian citizens are similar in that both need an NOC from your employer.

My current company has a 2 month notice period, so I won't be able to get an NOC from them as I'd have put in my papers by then. So I am wondering if it would suffice to explain this situation in the cover letter and enclose offer letter from my new employer. Has anyone done something like this?

K

Comment: I don't think Japan needs NOC. For Europe you could have shown your offer letter etc. What did you end up doing?